# Proper way to backup in-memory SQLite DB in a separate thread

Tags: delphi, firedac

I use the example from docwiki

```
FDConnection1.DriverName := 'SQLite';
FDConnection1.Open;

FDSQLiteBackup1.Database := '\\srv\db\data.sdb';
FDSQLiteBackup1.DestDatabaseObj := FDConnection1.CliObj;
FDSQLiteBackup1.DestMode := smCreate;
FDSQLiteBackup1.Backup;
```

The database FDConnection1 is working in the main thread. I want to save it back to file storage in a separate thread, cause this operation is taking much time

```
procedure TDBSaver.Execute; // separate thread
begin
  IntBackup.DriverLink := Link;
  IntBackup.WaitForLocks := true;
  IntBackup.DestDatabase:= '\\srv\db\data.sdb';
  IntBackup.DatabaseObj := FDConnection1.CliObj;
  IntBackup.Backup;
end;
```

Is this approach thread-safe?

Comment: You might do better to give the thread object its own FDConnection and assign its properties from `FDConnection1` before executing it.

Comment: Database connections are per-thread, which means that to backup from a thread you'll have to give that thread it's own new connection (which should be created by the thread in it's constructor)..

Comment: @KenWhite sry could you plz explain more, Im a bit confused - if i use new connection inside the backuper thread, how do I point that connection to my main in-memory database ?